# What is the common name for this widget (vertical buttons/links)?

Tags: terminology

What is the common name for this widget?

[image: Two buttons/links, "Submit Ticket" and "Live Chat", with vertical text]

Comment: I take it you're looking for something more specific than "tabs"?

Comment: I'd call it a Side Tab - but there may be an official answer.

Comment: Side Tabs with Vertical Text or simply Vertical Tabs

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered within seconds using any search engine.

Comment: Yes, any question that can be answered quickly should not be asked here, this place is too good for that kind of question.  Then again, most questions on this site can be answered quickly with a simple google search, why are people coming here?

Comment: how would someone perform a search on something he doesn't know how to call? OK, Google is smart, guess if I type "those colorful things at the side of some pages" almighty Google knows the answer. I'm scared, TBH

Answer (score 3):

They are called **Vertical Tabs**

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742441(v=vs.85).aspx#guidelines

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

Comment: I'd call them vertical tabs as well, but your reference is clearly depicting something else...

Comment: they are vertical tabs, just because they are not the same shape, doesn't mean they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to call them `flush (right|left) tabs` to imply that they normally exist outside the normal flow of the layout. But that's just a convention. Just saying vertical tabs tends to imply that they are part of the normal layout.